# Css z-index and transform weird flash

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Click on the image in snippet (expand full page) to run transform and look more closely at bottom right corner when animated card goes behind, you will see it overlaps slightly when it shouldn't. I happens when I apply `z-index` on each box div in CSS. If I remove `z-index`, there is no flash, but I need z-indexes on my box divs. Otherwise I cant have stack behave in such when I shuffle them (unless I change DOM order which I don't want). I have tried with some `backface-visibility` in CSS but with no luck. How could I get rid of such flash?

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {

  var box = $('#a2')

  box.one("transitionend", function() {

    box.css("zIndex", -1).one("transitionend", function() {

    }).removeClass('t').addClass('t2')

  }).addClass('t')


})
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #484848;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 370px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

#a1 {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: rotate(-4.5884deg);
}

#a2 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.t {
  transform: translateX(370px) rotate(23deg) !important;
}

.t2 {
  transform: translateX(0) rotate(-7deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="a1">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="box" id="a2">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/02.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Happens in all browsers from what I can see.

Comment: There is no flash in above code snippet.

Comment: Expand snippet fullscreen and look more closely at bottom right corner when animated card goes behind, you will see it overlaps slightly when it shouldnt. At least in chrome.

Comment: Are you talking about the z-index not transitioning at the correct time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *fix* is actually simple - just add `transition-property: transform` because that *is* what you want to *transform* (`transition-property: all` is the default and `z-index` is also *transitioned*).

See demo below:

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {
  var box = $('#a2')
  box.one("transitionend", function() {
    box.css("zIndex", -1).removeClass('t').addClass('t2')
  }).addClass('t')
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #484848;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 370px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition-property: transform; /* added */
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

#a1 {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: rotate(-4.5884deg);
}

#a2 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.t {
  transform: translateX(370px) rotate(23deg) !important;
}

.t2 {
  transform: translateX(0) rotate(-7deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="a1">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="box" id="a2">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/02.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

**Why the flicker?**

Note that `z-index` is an integer and it doesn't make much sense to *transition* it - the animation type is *integer* according to [**`MDN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/integer#Interpolation):

> When animated, values of the  data type are interpolated
>   using discrete, whole steps. The calculation is done as if they were
>   real, floating-point numbers; the discrete value is obtained using the
>   floor function. The speed of the interpolation is determined by the
>   timing function associated with the animation.

See a sample of how you can animate `z-index`:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container .box {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: stack 5s infinite linear;
}

.box + div {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box + div + div {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

@keyframes stack {
  50% {
    z-index: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

*This is **why** you have the flicker in your animation.*

Answer (score 0):

I think it is merely an order problem.
Just place the `.css (" zIndex ", -1)` next to the `.addClass ('t')`:
this way flash doesn't happen since z-index is applyed before the backward translation

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {
  var box = $('#a2')
  box.one("transitionend", function() {
    box.removeClass('t').addClass('t2')
  }).css("zIndex", -1).addClass('t')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code with `jQuery` update. Actually i just move your `box.css("zIndex", -1).addClass('t');` script in `setTimeout` method. Try this I hove it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {

  var box = $('#a2')
  box.one("transitionend", function() {
    box.one("transitionend").addClass('t2');
  })
  setTimeout(function(){
    box.css("zIndex", -1).addClass('t');
  })

})
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #484848;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 370px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

#a1 {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: rotate(-4.5884deg);
}

#a2 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.t {
  transform: translateX(370px) rotate(23deg) !important;  
}

.t2 {
  transform: translateX(0) rotate(-7deg) !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="a1">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="box" id="a2">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/02.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried increasing the z-index of the succeeding image and it works.

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {

  var box = $('#a2')
  var i=0;
  box.one("transitionend", function() {
    // increase the z-index
    $("#a1").css("zIndex", 99);
  
    box.css("zIndex", -1).one("transitionend", function() {

    }).removeClass('t').addClass('t2')

  }).addClass('t')


})
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #484848;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 370px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

#a1 {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: rotate(-4.5884deg);
}

#a2 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.t {
  transform: translateX(370px) rotate(23deg) !important;
}

.t2 {
  transform: translateX(0) rotate(-7deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="a1">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="box" id="a2">
  <img src="http://interactivepixel.net/tst/02.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```